# Divergences using MySql user variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with several name and I wish to remove a few suffixes from those name before searching for equivalences on a second table.

In order to do this, I decide to store the column I wish to modify in a variable and modify said variable for comparison in my second table.

Query before modifications:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.name
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.id IN (
   SELECT T2.id
   FROM Table2 T2
   WHERE T2.textBlock like concat('%', T1.name, '%')
)
```

New query with user variable (for testing, all operations on @newName were removed)

```
SELECT *, @newName:=T1.name
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.id IN (
   SELECT T2.id
   FROM Table2 T2
   WHERE T2.textBlock like concat('%', @newName, '%')
)
```

The first query returns 590 results. The second query, even if no modifications to the variable, returns 225 results. What could be causing this difference in the results?

Comment: Neither query should work because `%` should cause a parsing error.  The correlated subquery is the right approach; there is no reason to think that a variable would work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the fields in the `SELECT` clause are processed well after the conditions in the `WHERE`; it is likely the value being used in the variable is whatever it happened to be before the query was even executed.

I am a big fan of user/session variables, but using them across clauses is VERY unreliable and the biggest reason they have such a bad reputation.

--- What you can do ---

I am not a huge fan of correlated subqueries; they have their purposes, and when they are actually needed very little else can be quite as elegant, but they are very rarely needed in my experience. You are better off with something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.id, T1.name
FROM (SELECT id, name, X AS trimmedName FROM Table1 ) AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 
   ON T1.id = T2.id 
   AND T2.textBlock LIKE concat('%', T1.trimmedName, '%')
;
```

The `LIKE` with a leading wildcard is still going to present you with performance hurdles though; but hopefully the `id` equality condition will negate that issue.

--- Alternately ---
I have not used them much, but I see people reporting good results using `EXISTS`. Something like this....

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.name
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM Table2 T2
   WHERE T2.id = t1.id AND T2.textBlock like concat('%', T1.name, '%')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Uueerdo. In this case, would you have a suggestion on how to perform the necessary modifications on the T1.name field for the subquery?

Comment: Your suggestion solved the problem. I simply added all string operations directly on the subquery. Not the most elegant way, but totally efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that your query is:

```
SELECT *, @newName:=T1.name
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.id IN (SELECT T2.id
                FROM Table2 T2
                WHERE T2.textBlock like concat('%', @newName, '%')
               );
```

I would expect this to have very unexplained results.  A variable assigned in one expression has no particular values when referenced in another.  You have no idea what the SQL optimizer might be doing.  In some versions of MySQL, the subquery may be evaluated for every row; in more recent versions, it might be evaluated once.

In any case, the first method is the correct way to write the query.  Why would you want to use a variable unnecessarily?

Comment: I used this variable because I need to employ several `@newName:=SUBSTRING_INDEX(@newName, 'some string', 1)` to remove undesired parts of the string (15 possible undesired suffixes, to be more specific).